# In App Purchase Product Request Not Working

Tags: objective-c, app-store-connect, in-app-purchase

I am trying to add some in app purchases to my ios app. Everything is done but i can't seem to get these iap to work. I lifted some code off of a tutorial wedsite and it seems to work on that project im not sure what i am doing wrong. These iap's are for in game gold and can be used multiple times.

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>

@interface IAP : UIViewController <SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver, UIAlertViewDelegate>




+(void)myIAPWithItem:(NSString *)Item;

@end
```

.m

```
#import "IAP.h"
#import "Money.h"

@interface IAP ()

@end

@implementation IAP;




#define kStoredData @"com.emirbytes.IAPNoobService"




+(void)myIAPWithItem:(NSString *)Item{
    if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]) {
        NSString *PurchaseAddress = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"TTE_%@kGold" , Item]];
```

The PurchaseAddress is the appid in itunesconnect for these iap's.

```
        SKProductsRequest *request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:PurchaseAddress]];

        request.delegate = self;
        [request start];


    } else {
        UIAlertView *tmp = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                            initWithTitle:@"Prohibited"
                            message:@"Parental Control is enabled, cannot make a purchase!"
                            delegate:self
                            cancelButtonTitle:nil
                            otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
        [tmp show];

    }



}


#pragma mark StoreKit Delegate

-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:{

                // show wait view here

                break;
            }
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:{

                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                // remove wait view and unlock feature 2

                UIAlertView *tmp = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                    initWithTitle:@"Complete"
                                    message:@"You have unlocked Feature 2!"
                                    delegate:self
                                    cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                    otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
                [tmp show];





                // apply purchase action  - hide lock overlay and
                NSLog(@"It worked!");

                // do other thing to enable the features

                break;
            }
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:{
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                // remove wait view here
                                break;
            }
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:{

                if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled) {
                    NSLog(@"Error payment cancelled");
                }
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                // remove wait view here
                               break;
            }
            default:{
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{

    // remove wait view here


    SKProduct *validProduct = nil;
    int count = [response.products count];

    if (count>0) {
        validProduct = [response.products objectAtIndex:0];

        SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:@"com.emirbytes.IAPNoob.01"];
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];


    } else {
        UIAlertView *tmp = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                            initWithTitle:@"Not Available"
                            message:@"No products to purchase"
                            delegate:self
                            cancelButtonTitle:nil
                            otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
        [tmp show];

    }


}

-(void)requestDidFinish:(SKRequest *)request
{

}

-(void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to connect with error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}



#pragma mark AlertView Delegate

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

@end
```

So when i run it nothing happens. I can see it sends the product request but after that nothing. Does anyone know what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if your response.products count is nil?
do u take no products to purchase mistake?
try to give some more information, maybe can help better.
Also i think this is not your purchase product Id

```
SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:@"com.emirbytes.IAPNoob.01"];
```

Comment: I fixed the problem im not sure what it was though. ill post the code later tonight.